# Scanf causing segmentation fault - time on the input

Tags: c

I am having some problems with basic code that I wrote, it's supposed input hour in the following format hh::mm while operating on structure.

Can someone please tell me how should I scanf this type of input to get it into the array of structure?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Time 
{
  int hour; 
  int minutes; 
}t_time[2]; 

int main()
{
   puts("Please enter first hour in the following format hh::mm\n"); 

   scanf("%d::%d", t_time[1].hour, t_time[1].minutes); 

   puts("Please enter second hour in the following format hh::mm\n"); 

   scanf("%d::%d", t_time[1].hour, t_time[1].minutes); 

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [scanf()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) before using it.

Comment: ok, I added & to both variable in structure, now it's skipping to second question and not taking another hour.

Answer (score 3):

The `scanf()` arguments are expected to be pointers. You should precede the variable names with `&` operator, like this:

```
scanf("%d::%d", &t_time[1].hour, &t_time[1].minutes);
```

Also, in the first `scanf()`, you should pass the `0`<sup>th</sup> index of `t_time` array.

Additional:

`puts()` appends a newline character at the end automatically. You don't need to explicitly add `\n` at the end of string passed to `puts()`.

Comment: you're right, but it didn't help much - got rid of segmentation fault, but still second hour can't be entered. It's only gets to the second puts and that's it - can't enter second hour.

Comment: @RicchardHammond What is form of your input that you are giving? Can you share the input. Note that input should be in form - <num>::<num>.

Comment: I want to enter hour with the following format: 13:51 or 13::51 - both doesn't work. I need to allow this code to get the hour in this format with one or two colons

Comment: @RicchardHammond `13::51` input should work fine. I have tried on my machine, `13::51` on first prompt then it is asking second question. Note that `13:51` will not work as you have using `::` in `scanf()`. So, the input should be in format `<hour>::<min>`.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you are using the same index **1** for both times. You need to use index **0** for the first element and index **1** for the second element.

Secondly, you are passing the array elements' values to `scanf()` when `scanf()` expects their addresses. Use the address-of unary operator `&` for this purpose:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Time {
    int hour;
    int minutes;
} t_time[2];


int main(void) {
    puts("Please enter first hour in the following format hh::mm");

    scanf("%d::%d", &t_time[0].hour, &t_time[0].minutes);

    puts("Please enter second hour in the following format hh::mm");

    scanf("%d::%d", &t_time[1].hour, &t_time[1].minutes);

    printf("%d::%d\n", t_time[0].hour, t_time[0].minutes);
    printf("%d::%d\n", t_time[1].hour, t_time[1].minutes);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're right, but how can I modify this code to allow user to input hour in the format with hh colon mm like: 13:51 or 13::51

Comment: Suggest: read the first data via `scanf()`, then (in a loop) use `getchar()` to input the next char When the char input is a digit, the call `ungetc()` to put that last character back into `stdin` then input the second value using `scanf()`